# The processing speed between swift and objective-c in Metal

Tags: objective-c, swift, metal

I have written a demo base on apple official document in swift. And I found the usage of CPU is lower in Objective-c than in swift.

Does it mean Objective-c is much effective than swift while handling metal app?

I'm confused because many people says that swift is faster than Objective-c in general. Or it is just an exception？

The demo involved pointer management. I know it is trouble handle pointer with swift. Maybe it is the reason why the app is cost much resource in swift? I am still finding.

***The demo below is a triple buffer model which renders hundreds of small quads, updates their positions at the start of each frame and writes them into a vertex buffer. And uses semaphores to wait for full frame completions in case the CPU is running too far ahead of the GPU.***

This is the part of code from apple official document

```
- (void)updateState
{

    AAPLVertex *currentSpriteVertices = _vertexBuffers[_currentBuffer].contents;
    NSUInteger  currentVertex = _totalSpriteVertexCount-1;
    NSUInteger  spriteIdx = (_rowsOfSprites * _spritesPerRow)-1;

    for(NSInteger row = _rowsOfSprites - 1; row >= 0; row--)
    {
        float startY = _sprites[spriteIdx].position.y;
        for(NSInteger spriteInRow = _spritesPerRow-1; spriteInRow >= 0; spriteInRow--)
        {
            vector_float2 updatedPosition = _sprites[spriteIdx].position;

            if(spriteInRow == 0)
            {
                updatedPosition.y = startY;
            }
            else
            {
                updatedPosition.y = _sprites[spriteIdx-1].position.y;
            }

            _sprites[spriteIdx].position = updatedPosition;

            for(NSInteger vertexOfSprite = AAPLSprite.vertexCount-1; vertexOfSprite >= 0 ; vertexOfSprite--)
            {
                currentSpriteVertices[currentVertex].position = AAPLSprite.vertices[vertexOfSprite].position + _sprites[spriteIdx].position;
                currentSpriteVertices[currentVertex].color = _sprites[spriteIdx].color;
                currentVertex--;
            }
            spriteIdx--;
        }
    }
}


- (void)drawInMTKView:(nonnull MTKView *)view
{
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(_inFlightSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    _currentBuffer = (_currentBuffer + 1) % MaxBuffersInFlight;

    [self updateState];

    id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [_commandQueue commandBuffer];
    commandBuffer.label = @"MyCommand";

    __block dispatch_semaphore_t block_sema = _inFlightSemaphore;
    [commandBuffer addCompletedHandler:^(id<MTLCommandBuffer> buffer)
    {
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(block_sema);
    }];

    MTLRenderPassDescriptor *renderPassDescriptor = view.currentRenderPassDescriptor;

    if(renderPassDescriptor != nil)
    {
        id<MTLRenderCommandEncoder> renderEncoder =
        [commandBuffer renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor:renderPassDescriptor];
        renderEncoder.label = @"MyRenderEncoder";

        [renderEncoder setCullMode:MTLCullModeBack];
        [renderEncoder setRenderPipelineState:_pipelineState];

        [renderEncoder setVertexBuffer:_vertexBuffers[_currentBuffer]
                               offset:0
                              atIndex:AAPLVertexInputIndexVertices];

        [renderEncoder setVertexBytes:&_viewportSize
                               length:sizeof(_viewportSize)
                              atIndex:AAPLVertexInputIndexViewportSize];

        [renderEncoder drawPrimitives:MTLPrimitiveTypeTriangle
                          vertexStart:0
                          vertexCount:_totalSpriteVertexCount];

        [renderEncoder endEncoding];

        [commandBuffer presentDrawable:view.currentDrawable];
    }

    [commandBuffer commit];
}
```

and this is in swift

```
func updateSprite() {
    let currentSpriteVertices = vertexBuffer[currentBuffer].contents().bindMemory(to: DFVertex.self, capacity: totalSpriteVertexCount * MemoryLayout<DFVertex>.size)
    var currentVertex = totalSpriteVertexCount - 1
    var spriteIdx = (rowsOfSprites * spritePerRow) - 1
    for _ in stride(from: rowsOfSprites - 1, through: 0, by: -1) {
        let startY = sprites[spriteIdx].position.y
        for spriteInRow in stride(from: spritePerRow - 1, through: 0, by: -1) {
            var updatePosition = sprites[spriteIdx].position
            if spriteInRow == 0 {
                updatePosition.y = startY
            } else {
                updatePosition.y = sprites[spriteIdx - 1].position.y
            }
            sprites[spriteIdx].position = updatePosition

            for vertexOfSprite in stride(from: DFSprite.vertexCount - 1, through: 0, by: -1) {
                currentSpriteVertices[currentVertex].position = DFSprite.vertices[vertexOfSprite].position + sprites[spriteIdx].position
                currentSpriteVertices[currentVertex].color = sprites[spriteIdx].color

                currentVertex -= 1
            }

            spriteIdx -= 1
        }
    }

}

func draw(in view: MTKView) {

    inFlightSemaphore.wait()

    currentBuffer = (currentBuffer + 1) % maxBufferInFlight

    updateSprite()

    let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()
    if commandBuffer == nil {
        print("create command buffer failed.")
    }
    commandBuffer!.label = "command buffer"

    commandBuffer!.addCompletedHandler { (buffer) in
        self.inFlightSemaphore.signal()
    }

    if let renderPassDescriptor = view.currentRenderPassDescriptor,
        let renderEncoder = commandBuffer!.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptor) {
        renderEncoder.setCullMode(.back)
        renderEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineState!)

        renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer[currentBuffer],
                                      offset: 0,
                                      index: DFVertexInputIndex.vertex.rawValue)

        renderEncoder.setVertexBytes(&viewportSize,
                                     length: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: viewportSize),
                                     index: DFVertexInputIndex.viewportSize.rawValue)

        renderEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .triangle,
                                     vertexStart: 0,
                                     vertexCount: totalSpriteVertexCount)
        renderEncoder.endEncoding()
        commandBuffer!.present(view.currentDrawable!)
    }
    commandBuffer!.commit()
}
```

the result is that the app written in objective-c cost about 40% cpu usage while about 100% in swift. I thought swift would be faster.

Comment: You'll need to profile the two versions in Instruments to see where they are spending CPU and where they are blocked waiting for the GPU. Also, besides the difference in CPU usage, are there other performance differences? For example, does one version achieve a higher frame rate than the other?

Comment: And when you're profiling, make sure to enable optimizations. Swift with optimizations disabled can be slow-ish.

Comment: I.e. did you do a release build or a debug build for your Swift example. By default, debug builds have all optimizations turned off.

Comment: @Rob  Thanks. When doing a release build this demo just cost about 10% cpu usage! And what is interesting is that doing a release build in objective-c cause nearly no optimization(still cost about 40% cpu usage).

Comment: Swift offers the best of both worlds, offering more safety checks in non-optimized builds, but good performance in optimized builds.